# jQuery tablesorter plugin - perform an action AFTER table is sorted

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, highlight

I have a table which is sorted successfully using the tablesorter plugin. However, I want to highlight the text in a particular text field in a particular row. It has a unique ID, but when I place my code after the sorting code it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery("#filetable").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[3,1]],
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    testExtraction: "complex"
  });
  //my new code which doesn't work as expected
  if(jQuery("#new_foldername").length > 0){ 
    jQuery("#new_foldername").focus(function() { jQuery(this).select(); } ); 
  }
});
```

If I stick an alert just after the check to see if the #new_foldername exists, I see the alert, and I see the text highlighted in the background (so my code to highlight the text works). When I click to close the alert, then the table finishes sorting... and the text is not highlighted any more.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 5):

it seems the sorting is happening asynchronously. the documentation provides a hook called  'sortEnd' where you probably want to run your highlighting code. see example from 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-triggers.html

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin, the magic happens in the markup 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 

    //assign the sortStart event 
    $("table").bind("sortStart",function() { 
        $("#overlay").show(); 
        }).bind("sortEnd",function() { 
        $("#overlay").hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert,

Unfortunately sortEnd is only run when you click on a column heading to sort by. It doesn't work on the initial sort...

Instead I created a new widget like so:

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addWidget({ 
  id: "highlightNewFolder", 
  // format is called when the on init and when a sorting has finished 
  format: function(table) { 
    if(jQuery("#new_foldername").length > 0){  
      jQuery("#new_foldername").focus();
    }
  } 
});
```

This now works. Unfortunately I had to drop the selecting/highlighting of all the text. For some reason when the code had 'select()' within it, not even the focusing worked:

```
jQuery("#new_foldername").focus(function() { jQuery(this).select(); } );
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to focus AND highlight all text, then that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`initialized` callback function](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#initialized) *(or bind to the [`tablesorter-initialized` event](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#tablesorter-initialized))* ([source](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1086#issuecomment-157546229)) *Note: Those only work on [Mottie's fork of tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter), not the original (v2.0.5).*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#filetable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[3, 1]],
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        testExtraction: "complex",
        initialized: function() {
            if (jQuery("#new_foldername").length > 0) {
                jQuery("#new_foldername").focus(function() {
                    jQuery(this).select();
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Wow that was a while ago I posted this! I've since moved onto using Datatables now, so unable to test your suggestion, but it sounds plausible...!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something has changed.  The answers did not work for me, but this does:

```
$("#filetable").tablesorter().bind("sortEnd", function (e, t) {
    customHilite();
});
```

Zebra plugin did not work for me. maybe because of the way I was filtering rows.